# Is reading xml simple in rails or converting it to hash will be simpler?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby, xml-serialization, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Sorry for this question but after spending 1-2 hours on how to read xml, i thought posting it on forum will be better.
So i get a complex (very large)xml response from the plugin trackify. i want to read some values from it so i convert it into hash and then read it as follows
For ex:- to read city

```
@tracking_info['TrackResponse']['Shipment']['ShipTo']['Address']['City'] #>>  "SEATTLE"
```

my question is it proper way to getting xml response or there are some xml methods which is simple to use?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the [Nokogiri gem](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri) which makes this sort of thing easy.

Answer (score 1):

If converting to hash works for you, use it. However, working with XML is not much harder, given the libraries available. [REXML](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/rexml/rdoc/index.html) should be included in the Core, and it gives you basic XPath support to access the nodes by path:

```
s = "<a><b>1</b><b><c>2</c></b><c>pola</c><b>3</b></a>"
x = REXML::Document.new s
x.root.elements['/a/b/c'].text
#=> "2"
```

Take a look at the [tutorial](http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml/docs/tutorial.html).